# split url with comma and semicolon

Tags: angular7

I have image URL string like this

```
"Image1.jpg,Image2.jpg;Image3.jpg";
```

Now I want to split my imageurls with both comma and semicolon and store it into some array so how can I achieve that

Comment: You should be able to use the regex overload of the `string.split()` function which is inherited from JavaScript.

Comment: can u give me some example so i can understand how to use split for both comma and semicolon on single string

Comment: SenAnan already has. And google has many more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JS: use a regex for the split function separator:

```
const url = "Image1.jpg,Image2.jpg;Image3.jpg";
const arr = url.split(/[,;]+/);
```